# Как считать строку из txt файла python и использовать ее в качестве пути до файла

Tags: python

Есть такой код.
В переменную `save_file` присваивается путь до файла для сохранения данных.
Данный путь в виде строки сохраняется в файл `path.txt`
При попытке считать строку с путем до файла с данными и чтобы использовать ее повторно, появляется ошибка:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper

В чем заключается проблема?

```
def choose_path():
    global path
    global save_file
    save_dir = input('Использовать указанный в прошлый раз файл [yes/да] или указать/создать новый [no/нет]?')
    if save_dir == 'no' or save_dir == 'n' or save_dir == 'nah' or save_dir == 'nope' or \
            save_dir == 'нет' or save_dir == 'не' or save_dir == 'н' or save_dir == 'неа':
        save_file = input('Укажите путь для сохранения файла либо путь до существующего файла: ')
        path = open("path.txt", 'w')
        path.write(save_file)
        pass_type_request()
    elif save_dir == 'yes' or save_dir == 'ye' or save_dir == 'y' or \
            save_dir == 'да' or save_dir == 'д' or save_dir == 'da' or save_dir == 'd':
        path = open("path.txt", 'r')
        save_file = path
        pass_type_request()
```

Comment: Вы бв писали хоть стейк-трейс полностью. Где оно в коде, это ваше считывание?

Comment: В данном elif: 
path = open("path.txt", 'r')
save_file = path

Открывается файл path.txt в режиме считывания и строка из него присваивается в переменную save_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = open("path.txt", 'r')
save_file = path
```

Вы только откроили файл, а **не читали из его**.

Значит, в переменной `save_file` не будет *содержание файла,* т.е. текст, а *самый файл*, т.е. объект типа `TextIOWrapper`.

**Правильно:**

```
with open("path.txt") as inp:              # Не надо 'r', оно стандартно (но может быть)
    save_file = inp.readline().strip()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Holvender, не стоит. :-)